# Header flickers in and out of existence

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

In **Firefox**, if you place your mouse cursor over the **Hover cursor over me** text in the table area and use your mousewheel to scroll, the sticky **Column Header** will flicker and sometimes not render.

Giving the header a min-height: 0  or webkit-transform: translateZ(0) doesnt help much.

```js
const dr = document.querySelector(".duplicate-row");

for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  dr.after(dr.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```css
.table-header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}
td {
  padding: 16px;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<p>In <strong>Firefox</strong>, if you place your mouse cursor over the <strong>Hover cursor over me</strong> text in the table area and use your mousewheel to scroll, the sticky <strong>Column Header</strong> will flicker and sometimes not render.</p>

<p>If you move your cursor out of the table, or hover it on the <strong>Column Header</strong> and then try to use the mouse wheel to scroll then the flickering appears to go away.</p>

<p>If you use the vertical scroll bar to scroll the issue is less apparent.</p>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="table-header">
      <td>
        <h1>COLUMN HEADER</h1>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="duplicate-row">
      <td>Hover cursor over me</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you're describing in Firefox 94 on Windows 10 with AMD Radeon graphics.

Comment: Can actually reproduce with Firefox 94.0 on KDE Neon (Linux) with Nvidia 1070m

Comment: Likely to be a FF bug (can't reproduce on other browsers)

Comment: Yep: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1585378

Comment: Appears to be resolved in Firefox 95 (beta).